# Let variables on neighbor patches influence turtles decisions

Tags: patch, netlogo, turtle-graphics

my problem right now is the following:

I wan't my turtles to decide whether they move forward-left or forward-right each step they take. Target is to model some kind of semi-random movement pattern from south-west to noth-east. I called it semi-random because their choice should partially depend on how many other turtles already stepped on neighbor-patches.

My idea to solve this problem is the following:

Every patch owns a variable which grows with every turtle that comes by.

For the turtle's decision I use the random-float command to get a number between 0 and 99. I use if-else to let it move left-forward if the number generated is <50 if not i let it move right-forward. The last step I need would be to let the values of the variables of the neighbor-patches (left-forward and right-forward) influence the random-float. For that reason I need to somehow grab these values and add or subtract them from the random-float number.

To clarify this here the algorithm I was thinking about:

1. Generate a number between 0 and 99.
2. Get the variable's values of the both patches you could possibly move to (forward-left and forward-right).
3. Subtract the value you got from left-forward and add the value you got from right-forward to the generated number.
4. Check if the number is smaller 50

   - If it is: Move to the patch forward-left.
   - If it is not: Move to the patch forward-right.

End

My question is What command could I use to grab values from neighbor-patches and use them within these calculations?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for `patch-left-and-ahead` and `patch-right-and-ahead`.  Do you need something else?

Comment: Yes I need the command or a concept to grab values from the neigbor field's variables and use them.

Comment: something like

"set variable1 patch-left-and-ahead variable2"

Comment: Now it sounds like you are asking about `of`, as in `ask turtles set variable1 [variable2] of patch-left-and-ahead 45 1.4`.  Am I understanding your question?

Comment: yep, that seems to be it. i'll try this one. 

thank you :)